# Error on cabal build - Encounterd missing dependesies

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, cabal

I followed the instructions on lecture one - part 3 and I was trying to start week 1 project.
When I run cabal build got the following error:

[nix-shell:~/plutus-pioneer-program/code/week01]$ sudo cabal build

```
Warning: The build command is a part of the legacy v1 style of cabal usage.

Please switch to using either the new project style and the new-build command
or the legacy v1-build alias as new-style projects will become the default in
the next version of cabal-install. Please file a bug if you cannot replicate a
working v1- use case with the new-style commands.

For more information, see: https://wiki.haskell.org/Cabal/NewBuild

Resolving dependencies...
Warning: solver failed to find a solution:
Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: plutus-pioneer-program-week01-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: base (dependency of plutus-pioneer-program-week01)
[__1] rejecting: base-4.12.0.0/installed-4.1... (conflict:
plutus-pioneer-program-week01 => base^>=4.14.1.0)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: base, plutus-pioneer-program-week01)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: plutus-pioneer-program-week01, base
Trying configure anyway.
Configuring plutus-pioneer-program-week01-0.1.0.0...
cabal: Encountered missing dependencies:
aeson -any,
base >=4.14.1.0 && <4.15,
data-default -any,
playground-common -any,
plutus-contract -any,
plutus-ledger -any,
plutus-ledger-constraints -any,
plutus-tx -any,
plutus-tx-plugin -any
```

**Could not resolve dependencies** and **cabal: Encountered missing dependencies** is the errors here as far I can understand. I tried again by running cabal update and then cabal build but again I get the same error(s) that I described above. Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

try "cabal update" before "cabal build".

Comment: I tried it and it still does not work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using sudo? Try without.
And update of course.

Comment: If I don't I get an access denied error. I tried with update and it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Check and make sure that your version of the repo has the correct commit-id.